# Using AT Commands in QXDM

Tags: perl, at-command, qualcomm

I am trying to figure out a way to send AT Commands to a handset while it is being used by QXDM. I need to record some RF measurements and do this for a sequence of events (for an FTP UL session for example).

I had a look at example perl scripts under `C:\users\myuser\Documents\Qualcomm\Automation Samples` but could not find any script that uses a set of AT commands.

Is there a way in QXDM to achive this task?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I am not familiar with your environment, but you could try `Win32::SerialPort` or [roll your own](https://www.nu42.com/2015/08/playing-with-true-rng-hardware-random-number-generator.html).

Comment: Thanks Sinan! I noticed that I was using two COM ports to communicate with the handset within QXDM, while only one would be sufficient for QXDM to collect RF measurements, which leaves one spare COM port for modem communication. I found `Device::Modem` which has a method called `atsend()`....It is possible to write a Perl script to send AT commands to the modem, but still don't know how to execute/call that script within QXDM.

Comment: Can you share that script with me? I am trying to achieve that similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

There must be one more port other then diagnostic port. You can connect to it to send AT commands to the modem. You can use putty for that.